# How to synchronize on equal keys from different objects in Java

Tags: java, hashmap, synchronization

The method `calculate` is executed multiple times over different threads. Its result is then saved into a `HashMap`. Something like that:

```
void execute(){
     ...
     map.put(key, calculate(key);
}

Data calculate(Key key){
     ...
}
```

I want to prevent multiple executions over the same key, but I don't want to block all the threads. The ideal solution is to sync `calculate` over `Key`. The problem is that `Key` is not final, I can compare the keys and check if they are equal, but they will be different objects.

How do I solve this?

Comment: [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) 
 and maybe its `computeIfAbsent`!?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you could use a [`ConcurrentMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html) implementation (such as [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html)), and let [`computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) do the heavy lifting:

```
map.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> calculate(k));
```

Answer (score 2):

The computeIfAbsent might be optimistic according to the documentation. If you need a pessimistic solution, you could use striped lock. So you create an array of objects that can be locked and the hash of the key to find the lock.

```
private final Object[] locks = ....

synchronized(lock(key)){
    ...
}

Object lock(Object key){
      return locks[hashToIndex(key.hashcode())]
}
```

Comment: I like the idea, but you got two challenges to solve: How do you handle hash collisions? How do you clean up unused keys?

Comment: You just block if there is a collision. So make the array large enough so that the chance of a collision is very small. In the above example, no keys are stored so there is no unused key to remove.